# Can't find packages when running a python script from Ubuntu terminal

Tags: python, ubuntu, module, terminal, package

I wrote a python script in windows, but I need to execute in an Ubuntu machine (release 15.10). The problem is: 
When I try to run the script from the terminal using: `./script.py` I get the following error:

```
File "./script.py", line 7, in <module>
import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named 'pandas
```

I tried to solve the problem adding the following lines to my ~/.bashrc:

```
PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/:/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/"
export PYTHONPATH
```

but I'm still got in trouble. What am I missing?
My script starts with `#!/usr/bin/python3.5`. Is that wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: maybe it's a dumb question, but have you installed the required packages on ubuntu?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! I would recommend you not to use `PYTHONPATH` but rather to install `pandas` for Python 3 (e.g. `sudo apt-get install python3-pandas`).

Comment: Yep, all packages are properly installed. I also install the latest version of Anaconda.

Comment: If you are running the script in anaconda then you need to install pandas in the local environment of anaconda. https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pandas

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it works when I call `python script.py` on terminal, but I still can't understand why `./scrypt.py` does not work.